# Give all elements in Class an seperate Id Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

so i have an array with 4 images and I use javascript to load them in. Therefore I have created an "img" element using document.createElement("img")

I also used a forloop to push all 4 images.

I know how to give them a class with .className = "";
but i dont know how to give them all a seperate id in Javascript

How do I do that?

Comment: Why do they need IDs? What are you trying to solve here?

Comment: Just like with class: `.id = 'xxx'`

Comment: Well, I want to addEventListener("click") and I want all of them to give a certain number..

Comment: var addImage = document.createElement("img");
        addImage.className = "cssImages";
        addImage.setAttribute('src', Images[i]);
        IMGdiv.appendChild(addImage);

How do I give all 4 images a seperate id?

Comment: You can use the `for` index

Comment: You can add an event listener without giving them IDs.

Comment: yeah but how do i give all of them a seperate task when clicked?

Comment: in your for loop just add the index "i" to the class.. .className = "index_"+i;

Comment: `addImage.id = "img-" + i`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add attribute id using, `addImage.id="Image"+i;` or `setAttribute('id', "Image"+i)` like the following:

```
for(var i=0;i<Images.length;i++){
   var addImage = document.createElement("img"); 
   addImage.className = "cssImages"; 
   addImage.setAttribute('src', Images[i]); 
   addImage.setAttribute('id', "Image"+i);
   IMGdiv.appendChild(addImage);
}
```

Comment: *Spaces are not allowed in `id` attribute.*

Comment: What's wrong with with just `addImage.src` and `addImage.id`, why the need for `setAttribute`?

Comment: @Xotic750 there's nothing wrong with them, it's just a way of doing it.

Comment: In general I would suggest that for standard HTML attributes it is best to use the `.attribute` directly, and use `setAttribute` for non-standard attributes